# ActiveXObject in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, activexobject

I am having a hard time figuring out this problem. I have two different pages where I do the following query.

**Page 1 ->**

```
if (typeof(window.ActiveXObject) != "undefined")
  //returns true
```

**Page 2 ->**

```
if (typeof(window.ActiveXObject) != "undefined")
  //returns false
```

Pages are running on same browser IE11 and same IIS server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Different X-UA-Compatible meta tags could cause that; in IE11 window.ActiveXObject no longer exists outside of IE=EmulateXX

Comment: I added <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" /> and fixed the problem. Thanks Alex.